# Appending data in SAS and overwriting when it already exists

Tags: sas

I'm writing a macro job that appends a dataset to an existing one (the macro paramater is a date).

If that date exists, I want to overwrite the data for all of those dates.

What is the best way to tackle this?

If it was in SQL i would delete the rows the insert them.  Some SQL languages let you do a replace into if you state a Key.  Should I apply a similar theory to SAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways; no 'best' way exists, given different needs.

Delete and append is one option.  In SAS you would likely use `PROC APPEND` to do the append, after deleting in either `PROC SQL` or in a data step.  This has the advantage that it will work with many-to-many type relationships well, but it's typically slower than other options.

Using a simple datastep merge is also an effective way to do this.  This is probably the 'fastest' way if your master data is sorted and/or indexed by your PK and your append data is either sorted and/or indexed by the PK or is small enough sorting it isn't very expensive.  Here's an example:

```
data class_master;
  set sashelp.class;
  if _n_ < 10;
  origds='Master';
run;

data class_append;
  set sashelp.class;
  where sex='F';
  origds='Append';
run;

proc sort data=class_master;
  by name;
run;

proc sort data=class_append;
  by name;
run;


data class_final;
  merge class_master(in=_m) class_append(in=_a);
  by name;
run;
```

`Merge` naturally does what you're asking - it adds new records when a new record is found and updates records that are not new.  So long as the master and update table are identical in their variables and variable lengths, it will do the same thing effectively as a replace and update, if the merge is 1:1 (so the BY statement is by the primary key of both tables and each tables are unique on that primary key).

`Update` is similar to merge, except it only replaces non-null data with additional non-null data; so if a data row in the update set has null (missing) values for some variables, those won't be applied, on a variable by variable basis, to the master table.  So if that's desired, use `UPDATE` instead of `MERGE`.

You also have all of the ANSI SQL techniques available in `PROC SQL`, ie, using `UNION` to keep unique records, `DELETE/INSERT` combination to delete and insert, etc.; there is no `MERGE INTO` (that is in the data step) or most other non-ANSI SQL concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use `by` processing and `last.` (or `first.` depending on the requirements).

Example

```
data have1 ;
  input date date9. val 8. ;
datalines ;
01feb2015 10
04feb2015 2
10feb2015 16
;
run ;

data have2 ;
  input date date9. val 8. ;
datalines ;
02feb2015 12
04feb2015 18
11feb2015 21
;
run ;

data append ;
  set have1 
      have2 ;
  by date ;
  if last.date ;
run ;
/* Result : 
01feb2015 10
02feb2015 12
04feb2015 18
10feb2015 16
11feb2015 21
*/
```

Comment: This has the same need as merge for sorting (or indexing), don't forget.  You might want to explain how it differs from merge (which it is _nearly_ identical with, and if the datasets are truly identical in structure and you do no other processing in the merge step, will give identical results).